# Selection box in ggplotly for boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to create an interactive box plot that has a selection box tool (from plotly R). I currently am able to create an interactive box plot using plotly R; however, the plotly tools do not include the usual selection box. Is it possible to create an interactive box plot that has a selection box tool using plotly R?

Below is a MWE.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Name = paste0("Name",1:100), A=abs(rnorm(100)), B=abs(rnorm(100)), C=abs(rnorm(100)), D=abs(rnorm(100)), E=abs(rnorm(100)))
dat$Name <- as.character(dat$Name)
nVar = ncol(dat)
boxDat <- dat[, c(1:nVar)] %>% gather(key, val, -c(Name))
colnames(boxDat) <- c("Name", "Group", "Count")

BP <- ggplot(boxDat, aes(x = Group, y = Count)) + geom_boxplot()
ggBP <- ggplotly(BP)
```

Thanks for sharing any ideas!

Note: Below is an image of the lasso and box selection tools available in plotly R. In the top right of the plot, you can see all of the plotly option tools. The lasso and box selection tools are the fourth and fifth icons from the left (in an orange square). 
[image: Lasso and box selection tools in plotly R]

Comment: What do you mean by "usual selection box"?

Comment: Thanks @SBista. I just edited to make that more clear and included an image!